# Variable vs Constant

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, vb.net

I was wondering the differences of variable and constants as I see different declaration of variable/constant in the codes written by ex-colleagues.

I know that variable is something that can be change throughout the code and the value of constant is fixed and can't be changed. By far I've written everything in variable (even if the variable will not be change). Is it my practice is incorrect? Perhaps my code is not complicated therefore I use variable all the time.

Anyhow, if my understanding proven wrong, please enlighten me with the correct guidelines on this matter will do.

Comment: `CONSTANTS` will normally declared at the top of code page, or somewhere global. Which will not be changed throughout the application (also when you're coding, it will throw you an error of [Constant cannot be the target of an assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5e42zkx(v=vs.90).aspx) whenever you try to assign a value to it). Declaring a variable and use it as a CONSTANT is not safe as you might accidentally update or changed the value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems like the purpose of Constant is to prevent programmer to change the value by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good code practice to use constants whenever possible.

At runtime / compile time it will be known that only Read operations can be done on those values, thus some accessing / IO  optimizations will be done to the code automatically , which will significantly increase performance.

Another difference is that constants are stored in a different preallocated section of your code (compiler dependent, but on most compilers this is what happens), which makes them easier to access , and they don't get allocated / deallocated all the time (so another performance optimization).

And finnaly, constants can be evaluated at compile time .

For example, if you have an ecuation of constants, something like the following :

```
 float a = const1 * const2 / const3 + const4;
```

Then the whole expression will be evaluated at compile time, saving cycles at runtime (since the value will always be the same).
Some popular constants that refer to this sort of optimization are PI , PI/2 , PI/4, 1/PI.

Comment: Hi there, can you share any links regarding PI, PI/2 etc to me? That would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know exactly what information you are searching for with links to PI and PI/2 . Here's a link to a Math.h header from c : http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/math_8h_source.html . In C# you have Math.PI defined in Math : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math_fields(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
   const int const_a = 10;
   int static_a = 70;

    public void sample()
    {
        static_a = const_a+10; //This is correct
       // const_a=88; //It is wrong
    }
```

In the above example, if we declare the variable as const we can't able to assign the value from anywhere but we can use that variable.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, instead of just writing a code, so that it could be more useful for the OP and other people with the same  question.

Comment: Thanks for your example. In fact I understand this, don't worry.